# how to delete duplicate data table in SQL with PHP

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to delete duplicate data from a table, but keeping the 1º record tha was made, the first id of this data.
But i need to delete using specific period parameters which i already know contains duplicates, the duplicate data are from 12th of this month.

Here's PHP code that i'm using:

```
require("../conn/conn.php");
require("../conn/conn-relatorio.php");
require("../funcoes/funcoes.php");
$URL = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];


$query = "DELETE FROM tb_relatorio08_cdsdetalhado WHERE
cd_codigo NOT IN (SELECT MIN(cd_codigo) AS 'ID' FROM tb_relatorio08_cdsdetalhado GROUP BY cd_supervisor, nu_at, nu_tipoServico)
 and DAY(dt_cadastro) = 12 AND MONTH(dt_cadastro) = 1 AND YEAR(dt_cadastro) = 2022";


$result = $connRelatorio->query($query);


if ($result->error) {
    echo "Error: " . $result->error;
}else{
    echo "sucesso.";
}


?>
```

Doing the direct query in SQL it counts error 1093, saying thata i cannot specifiy the table for update in from, but i am not doing an update.

Where am i going wrong?

Comment: Can you post the content of "./conn/conn-relatorio.php" ?

Comment: What about foreign keys mapped to the table you are removing the duplicates in? Any ON DELETE/UPDATE CASCADE .. ?

Comment: Try removing the alias from the NOT IN subquery

Comment: Same Error Manuel.